# Delay html form submission until div animation complete

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery form validation plugin to validate my form. I have set up all the rules , messages etc. So in my html I have made a css styled dialog which simply is displayed to the user as a confirmation message.When a user registers this `div confirmation` simply fades in over the entire page before the form's action file is called. My question is how do I delay the forms submit action from triggering long enough for my confirmation to fade in and out. When I try it either straight away fires the submit OR doesn't do anything at all.

```
//validation plugin
$("#register_form").validate({
    errorClass: "invalid",
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: '0px'
        }, 300);
    },
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },

    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: "Enter your first name"
        },
        lastname: {
            required: "Enter your last name"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Enter your email",
            email: "Enter a valid email"
        }

    },

    errorContainer: $(".errorCont"),
    errorLabelContainer: $('.errorCont ul'),
    wrapper: 'li',

}); //Etc above all working its the code below

$("#register_form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#register_form").valid()) {
        showpopup();
        // Show popup and then proceed with submission action ??
        // calling submit here just submits straight away without waiting for pop to hide 
    }

});

function showpopup() {
    $('#dialog').fadeIn("slow");
    $("#bodywrap").css({
        "opacity": "0.3"
    });
    setTimeout(hidepopup, 3000);
}

function hidepopup() {
    $('#dialog').hide();
    $("#bodywrap").css({
        "opacity": "1");

    }
}
```

Comment: I've got confused. Do you want to wait for the animation if the forms validation succeeds?

Comment: yes at this point I simply want to... firstly validate the form. Then show the confirmation for 3 seconds.Then perform the action which is specified by the form (php file). After that I will then retrieve the form values etc etc

Comment: I have used the submitHandler already but when I was looking for solutions I noticed people mentioning to use `.submit`.

Comment: That's because the #1 way this plugin is abused is by using an external `click` or `submit` handler, and those "people" are simply ill-informed.  The plugin already captures the `submit` event with the built-in `submitHandler` callback function. It's fired when the form tests valid... exactly the opposite of the `invalidHandler` callback which you're already using properly.

Comment: @Sparky yes using the provided handler makes much more sense to. But it was just a lot of examples similar to my situation had the `.submit` as the solution. And I guess when I read the feedback it mislead me into thinking `.submit` is the more flexible solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *setTimeout*, use the *complete handler* of the [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) function.

```
$('#dialog').fadeOut("slow", function() {
    // This function will fire after the animation's ending
    // Submit the form from here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For submitting the form when validation passes you can use `submitHandler` method of the `validate` object, also jQuery's animating methods accept a callback function that is executed when the animation is complete.

Note that by default jQuery animates the element within 400 milliseconds, I have used `setTimeout` method just in case that the poor user has to wait 3000 milliseconds.

```
$("#register_form").validate({
    // ...
    // this function is executed when validation passes   
    submitHandler: function() {
       var that = this,
           $body = $("#bodywrap").css({ 
             "opacity": "0.3" 
           }),
           $dialog = $('#dialog');
       $dialog.fadeIn("slow", function(){
          setTimeout(function() {
             $body.css({"opacity": "1"});
             $dialog.fadeOut("slow", function(){
               that.submit();
             });
          }, 2600);
       });

    }
 });
```

Comment: What do you need the timeout for?

Comment: @Itay I have used timeout as OP uses `setTimeout(hidepopup, 3000);`. Actually I don't need it :).

Comment: I think he used it because he wanted to wait till the end of the animation :))

Comment: @Itay Well in that case it just takes 400 milliseconds not 3 seconds :)

Comment: so should I remove timeout ?

Comment: @user1927602 If you don't need it, yes, you can remove the `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Itay still doesn't work...its the same problem it doesn't do the submit action. The animation works but the submit has always been a problem.

Comment: the main thing Im trying to achieve is that the user actually sees the confirmation dialog for three seconds. The fade out isn't important.After three seconds I just need to set the opacity of the body back to default and simply hide the dialog box. Then I want  to perform the specified form action

Comment: @user1927602 Have you tried the code in my answer? It seems it should work as you have described, if yes and it still doesn't work: do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: yes I have exactly as you put it but my form has got `action ="reg_user.php"` and it is what i expect to be executed. After the dialog has been displayed. The easier option is to just scrap the confirmation dialog all together and it would work. So it would just submit the form straight away

Comment: @user1927602 Did you remember to switch the event to .validate() instead of .submit() like in undefined's code?

Comment: @Itay yes I put it inside my `validate` method like my `invalidHandler` . It doesn't matter I am doing it another way.I won't submit at all but rather use ajax

Comment: I don't understand why we're not just leveraging the animation's callback function to ensure the animation is complete before doing the next thing.